# In swift，is it a global variable or property?

Tags: swift, global-variables

> Global variables are variables that are defined outside of any
>   function, method, closure, or type context.《The Swift programming Guide》。

So this is a question：

```
class Dog {
    var name: String?
    func run(){

    }
}
```

name is a global variable or property?

```
@implementation Dog{

 NSString *name;
- (void)run{ 

   }
}
```

name is a global variable or property?

Answer (score 2):

Since a class is a type, `name` is a property in the Swift example.

In the Objective-C example, `name` is a global variable since properties are defined in the `@interface` scope and requires a `@property` declaration. (Instance variables don't require any declaration but they have to be inside a block inside the `@interface` or `@implementation` scopes.)

Comment: Thanks a lot,@Jesper

Answer (score 1):

`name` is inside a type context, `class Dog`, so it is a property of `Dog` instances.

The second example is similar to Objective-C (it definitely isn't Swift), but it's incorrect ObjC syntax. It's not clear what the actual code is. If you meant:

```
@implementation Dog 
NSString *name;
- (void)run {     
}
@end
```

then `name` is a global, but should never write it that way. It's very confusing. The `name` declaration should go outside the `@implementation` block to avoid confusion. If, on the other hand, you meant to write:

```
@implementation Dog {   
    NSString *name;
}

- (void)run {
}
@end
```

Then `name` is a private instance variable (which is not the same thing as a property). This is an unusual syntax in modern ObjC and should generally be avoided.

Comment: **Thanks**,you are right that the second example is Objective-C. I make a mistake. 

    ````@implementation ClassA { 
    + (instancetype)shareTools
    {
        return [[self alloc] init];
    }
        static Tools *_instance;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            _instance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
        });
        return _instance;
    }
    @end````
 Is **static Tools *_instance** a global?